# Al editar producto, rellenar multiselect con jquery, Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

hace algún tiempo hice la vista de crear un producto, y ahora llega la de editarlo.

Bien, al añadir un producto, tengo un select donde cargo unas subcategorias, según la que seleccione, tengo un botón de añadir que lo que hace es una consulta a través de AJAX, donde le mando una id de esa sub categoría y cargo un multiselect con los términos que tiene esa subcategoria, así pueden añadir lo que necesiten, también puedo añadir otra subcategoria y hace la misma función, me añade otro multiselect con los términos que puedo añadir.

Para entenderlo mejor, una subcategoria es por ejemplo "COLOR" y los valores del multiselect que puedo añadir (Términos), ejemp: azul, rojo, amarillo....

Entonces lo que necesito que no se si es posible, si este producto por ejemplo tiene, (Genero: Masculino, niño) y (Colores: rojo) que me salgan esos multiselects ya rellenados, pero claro con jquery.

La duda es que no se como tengo que proceder al hacerlo con Jquery.

**El selector de atributo (subcategoria)**
Estoy cargando los valores a través de una query en el controlador.

```
<select class="form-control myinputs col-4 inlinBlock" name="selAtributo[]" id="selAtributo">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona atriburo</option>
      @foreach ($atributos as $item)
        <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

**Función, con la que desplego los multiselect y los valores que puedo elegir**

```
function myFunction() {
        var atributo = document.getElementById("selAtributo").value;
        console.log(idProducto);
        $.get("select_atributo/" + atributo, function (data) {
        data.elAtributo = data.elAtributo || {};
        var atributoName = data.elAtributo.slug;
        var atributoNameBueno = data.elAtributo.name;
        if ($("select#" + atributoName).length) return;
        var htmlDivContainer = `<div class="form-group select-container-${atributoName}" style="position:relative;"></div>`;
        var htmlSelectContainer = `<div class="deplegables">${atributoNameBueno}</div><select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control formNuevo variaciones" name="${atributoName}[]" multiple="multiple" id="${atributoName}"></select><a class="removeclass posiPapelera"><i class="far fa-trash-alt eye"></i></a>`;
        $("#terminos1").append(htmlDivContainer);
        $(`#terminos1 div.select-container-${atributoName}`).html(
        htmlSelectContainer
        );
        var htmlOptions = (data.terminos || []).reduce(
        (html, termino, index) =>
        html + `<option value="${termino.slug}">${termino.termino}</option>`,
        ""
        );
        $(`#terminos1 select[name="${atributoName}[]"`).html(htmlOptions).select2();
        //console.log(data);
        });   
    }  
    $("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
    })
```

**El controlador**

```
public function sacaTerminos($atributo)
    {
        $terminos = Termino::where('atributo_id', $atributo)->get();
        $elAtributo = Atributo::where('id', $atributo)->first();
        return with(["terminos" => $terminos, "elAtributo" => $elAtributo]);
    }
```

Esto es como actuo cuando añado un producto, pero quiero saber si me podeis dar una noción de como actuar para rellenar en editar el producto lo que ya tiene.

**Tabla productos**

```
+----+------------+----------+---------------+
| id |    name    |categoria | subcategoria  |    
+----+------------+----------+---------------+
| 1  | sudadera   |     2    |       1       |
| 2  | camiseta   |     5    |       3       |
| 3  | pantalon   |     2    |       4       |
| 4  | deportivas |     9    |       5       |   
+----+------------+----------+---------------+
```

**Tabla donde se guardar la variaciones que tiene un producto**

```
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
| id | product_id | variant  | valor     |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1          | genero   | hombre    |
| 2  | 1          | color    | negro     |
| 3  | 1          | color    | rojo      |
| 4  | 1          | color    | blanco    |   
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Que es mejor, traer los datos en php o hacerlo todo en jquery?
Saludos

Comment: Por usabilidad, no te recomiendo poner este tipo de controles en un selectbox. Por la naturaleza de tus datos, esto califica más bien como "tags".
Revisa esta librería para que te des una idea: https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/
Puedes poner una instancia de Selectize por cada tipo de variante.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta @BaruchSpinoza pero si quisiera utilizar esto, como lo tendría que hacer?